# Success write files to external storage, but can't delete folder

Tags: android, android-external-storage

android studio 3.6

in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

here my viewmodel:

```
 init {
        Debug.d(TAG, "init: call_loadOperationHistory()")
        //loadOperationHistory()
        val saveImagesDir =
            AndroidUtil.getExternalStoragePath(getApplication<Application>().applicationContext)
        if (saveImagesDir.exists()) {
            val isDelete = saveImagesDir.delete()
            Debug.d(
                TAG,
                "init: isDelete = " + isDelete + ", saveImagesDir_delete = " + saveImagesDir
            )
        }
    }
```

and here util method:

```
public static File getExternalStoragePath(Context context) {
        File root = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File savedImagePath = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        return savedImagePath;
    }
```

I success write files to this dir. But can't delete this dir.

Method:

```
val isDelete = saveImagesDir.delete()
```

always return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide Read and Write permissions and Try with this:

```
File dir = new File("root path");
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

Add this line in gradle file to have Apache

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check same once adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Permission to manifest

Comment: Not help. Same result

Answer (score 0):

If the directory contains files then you cannot delete it with the File class.

Empty it first.